# Python selenium cant locate site's elements

Tags: python, html, selenium

The script need to go to "https:// example.com", paste a text and click a button.

How to do that with selenium?

For now, only the following code are working:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://example.com")
```

How to locate 2 elements?

But I guess site have some kind of script protection, maybe someone can solve this thing?

Comment: Show what have you tried so far. Site has nothing to do with script protection and target elements can be simply located. It seem that you made no efforts to solve your issue, but just looking for someone to write code for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just read the 'Getting Started' page. It's easy! Then, you can view the page in your browser and use it to examine the code behind the elements you want to play with. In Chrome it's simply a matter of right-clicking on a element (such as the text area) and then selecting 'Inspect' from the drop-down menu.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get('http://text.ru')
>>> text_area = driver.find_element_by_name('user-text')
>>> text_area.send_keys('hello, how are you?')
>>> red_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn_red')
>>> red_button.click()
```